# what does this mean in 'computeSVD()' python

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

my question is what does the number 5 refer to in this  `computeSVD(5, computeU=True)`:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix

rows = sc.parallelize([
    Vectors.sparse(5, {1: 1.0, 3: 7.0}),
    Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
    Vectors.dense(4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0)
])

mat = RowMatrix(rows)

svd = mat.computeSVD(5, computeU=True)  <--- the 5 here 
U = svd.U       # The U factor is a RowMatrix.
s = svd.s       # The singular values are stored in a local dense vector.
V = svd.V       # The V factor is a local dense matrix.
```

i found this code in this link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html

Comment: As written in the comment above the line: `Compute the top 5 singular values and corresponding singular vectors.` Does that answer your question? 5 indicates how many singular values and vectors you like to compute.

Comment: im using this function in a large matrix and i was using k as the number of columns on the matrix but i was getting an error ---> IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Requested k singular values but got k=110 and numCols=107.  so i tried to use k=107 and it worked fine , does it change anything if k is different ?

Comment: You might wanna read up on the theory behind SVD and dimensionality reduction. You cannot have more singular values than you have columns and usually you specify `k` to be much smaller than the number of columns.

Comment: alright, i understood better now thanks for your help that was usefull

Comment: i will try to check out  the theory part of svd